# How to see CSV File in WPF GUI (listview)?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I want to be able to see different CSV files in my listview (not at the same time).

The `.CSV` files have different columns.

I already wrote this method in my `GeneralLogic.cs` class:

```
public void readCSV(string filename, MainWindow mw)
{
    connectToDBLogic();

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.Default))
    {
        reader.ReadLine();

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            string[] values = line.Split(';');
        }
    }
}
```

This is my MainWindow method:

```
private void btnShowCSVClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    gl.readCSV(fileNameBox.Text, this);
}
```

But what do I have to add, that the table is shown in the listview? I called it listViewTable.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Hi, I'm from the future. We need to stop trying to using handmade CSV parser. I recommend using [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). It will be easy to map your csv to a list of custom object.

Comment: If there is any reason to not use third party lib, you could make it like: 
`listViewTable.Items.Add(String.Join(" ", array));`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListView` to the results returned by your `readCSV` method. Currently the method does not return any value.

Change `public void readCSV` to `public List<string[]> readCSV`.

Then you will need to bind columns of the `ListView` to fields in the `List` of `string[]`

Answer (score 0):

For now your `readCSV` returns nothing. Perhaps it could return the list of object that were save in the file. And the [bind it](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/) to the ListView.

### Getting the CSV value:

#### 1/. Without external Lib.

```
public void readCSV(string filename, MainWindow mw)
{
    var result = File.ReadAllLines(filename)
                .Select(line => line.Split(';'))
                .Select(x => new MyObject { 
                    prop1 = x[0],
                    prop2 = x[1],
                    //etc.. 
                })
    return result;
}
```

Or bind the result to the list like `myListView.ItemsSource =` .

But this method without an external parser will not handle error, malformed csv etc. But it's trivial with a simple lib.

#### 2/. With [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

Mapping information:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}

public sealed class MyClassMap : ClassMap<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassMap()
    {
        AutoMap();
        Map( m => m.CreatedDate ).Ignore();
    }
}
```

And you use it like :

```
var csv = new CsvReader( textReader );
var records = csv.GetRecords<MyClass>();
```

Exemple and code form [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

#### Binding:

Binding to the list view is trivial.

```
// Assign the source
myListView.ItemsSource = gl.ReadCSV();

// Add to existing items
myListView.Items.AddRange(gl.ReadCSV());
```